# Is there an estimate available for a sum of the form $\sum_{\mathbf{x} \equiv \mathbf{a} (H) } \mu^2(x_1 x_2)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am interested in a sum of the shape 
$$
\sum_{ \substack{ 1 \leq x_1, x_2 \leq B\\
 \mathbf{x} \equiv \mathbf{a} (H) } } \mu^2(x_1 x_2). 
$$
I figured it must have been considered before, but I have not been able to find a reference for it. Any information would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: The usual technique of writing $\mu^2(x_1x_2) = \sum_{d^2\mid x_1x_2} \mu(d)$ and reversing the order of summation should be a good start here; the new inner sum simply counts integers in an arithmetic progression and thus we have as good an error term as we could hope for (if $B$ is not too small in terms of $H$).